# Getting Platform declaration clash when using Interface in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm converting some classes in Java to kotlin and I'm running into compile errors when trying to inherit from an interface:

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
>   JVM signature (getContentID()Ljava/lang/String;):
>
> public open fun get-content-id (): String? 
>   public open fun getContentId(): String?

Here is the interface:

```
interface Media {
  val contentId: String

  val displayRunTime: String

  val genres: List<String>

  val programId: String

  val runTime: String

  val type: String
}
```

here is the class:

```
class Airing : Media {
  override val contentId: String? = null
  override val displayRunTime: String? = null
  override val genres: List<String>? = null
  override val programId: String? = null
  override val runTime: String? = null
  override val type: String? = null

  override fun getContentId(): String? {
    return contentId
  }
```

I'm super new to kotlin.

Comment: Have you defined variables or functions in your interface Media? Looks like they are variables (properties in Kotlin). I think you want to define a list of functions (methods in Java) and implement them in `Airling` class. Is it ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to declare `override fun getContentId(): String?`, because the `val contentId: String` from the `Media` interface is already overridden by `override val contentId: String?`.

The error that you get means that the function you declare clashes in the JVM bytecode with the getter that is already generated for the `contentId` property (the getter has the same signature).

In Kotlin, you should work with the property `contentId` directly, whereas in Java you can use the generated accessors `getContentId()` and `setContentId(...)`.

Also, Kotlin does not allow you to override a not-null `String` property with a nullable `String?` one, because the users of the base interface will expect a not-null value from the property. You should replace the overridden property types with `String`, or make them `String?` in the interface.

Comment: There is also the problem of overriding `String` properties with `String?` properties.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the type `T?` includes `T` and `null`. in turn, `T` is a subset of `T?`. so you can't override the `T` property with its superset type, for example:

```
interface Source { val content: Any }

//                               v--- ERROR: `Any?` is not a subtype of `Any`
class Image(override val content:Any?) : Source
```

However, you can override the `T?` property with its **subset type** or **subtype**, for example:

```
interface Source { val content: Any? }

//                              v--- `Any` is a subset of `Any?`
class Image(override val content:Any) : Source

// `String` is a subtype of `Any` & `Any?` includes `Any`
//                               v
class Text(override val content:String) : Source
```

Then your code should be as below. However, Kotlin is a null-safety system, you can't define a property without initializing it, even if the property is a **nullable** property:

```
class Airing : Media {
   //           v--- ERROR: the property isn't initialized      
   override val contentId: String
   ...
}
```

You should introduce properties in primary constructor to let the client code to initializing them in future, for example:

```
class Airing
constructor(
        override val contentId: String,
        override val displayRunTime: String,
        override val genres: List<String>,
        override val programId: String,
        override val runTime: String,
        override val type: String
) : Media
```

You also can provide some default value for the properties, for example:

```
class Airing : Media {
    override val contentId: String = "<default>"
    override val displayRunTime: String = "<default>"
    override val genres: List<String> = emptyList()
    override val programId: String = "<default>"
    override val runTime: String = "<default>"
    override val type: String = "<default>"
}
```

**AND** `getContentId` function will conflict with `getter`, so you should remove it.

Comment: *Note*: this rule apply immutable `val` property, because override method can provide its return type with subtype  in Java. in other words, you can't apply the rule in mutable `var` property.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared as `val` are like Java `final` variables, are inmutable so you cannot set as `Optional ?`

Your variable declaration should be like follows:

```
interface Media {
    var contentId: String?
    //...
}
```